# Plotting shapefiles in ggplot2: Print() error

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, shapefile

I am using ggplot2 for the first time to create a map showing local Moran's I in Houston. I began with a polygon shapefile of block groups with information on graphics. I am able to plot LISA, E.G. [image]

However, I would like to add a points layer on top of my map. My code is located inside of a function, hence the print command.

```
  # plot map
  df <- fortify(data, region = "id")
  df <- left_join(df, data@data)

  png(paste(file.path, "/OUTPUTS/LISA_MAP_", str.region, "_", str.var,
  ".png", sep = ""), height = 800, width = 800)

  lisa.map <- ggplot(df, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = quad_sig)) +
       geom_polygon(color = "white", size = .05) + coord_equal() +
       theme_void() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
       labs(title = paste("LISA map of", str.var, "in", 
                           str.region, sep = " "))

  lisa.map <- lisa.map + 
        geom_point(data = as.data.frame(coordinates(pt.data)), 
                   aes(x = coords.x1, y = coords.x2), color = "black") + 
        coord_equal()

  print(lisa.map) # this is throwing an error for some reason

  dev.off()
```

The error I keep receiving says "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'group' not found". In my traceback the error occurs at the print function. Before trying to add my points data, the plotting was successful. From what I gathered online something in the first ggplot call does not "transfer over" I guess to the second time I try to map the layers. However, I've been playing around with my code for a while and cannot figure out how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'll guess that it's because you have a group in your `aes`, which carries through to all the layers, but probably only have a `group` column in the shapefile and not the dataframe of points. If that's the case, remove `group` from the first `aes`, and then add `aes(group = group)` inside `geom_polygon`

Comment: @camille group is stored in the dataframe. I used group = group in each aes but it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: `coordinates(pt.data)` definitely has a column called `group`?

Comment: @camille group was located in df. However, I solved the issue by simplifying the plot. 'lisa.map <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = df, aes(long, lat, group = group)) + geom_point(data = as.data.frame(coordinates(pt.data)), aes(coords.x1, coords.x2))' and then I added additional commands from there. However, I'm still not sure why print() was throwing an error in the original code above.